# reload part twig in symfony2.2

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a template that has several twig. a part of the template is loaded in this way:

```
{{Render (controller ('BlogBundle: Post: list', {'limit': 2})}}
```

but inline edit this part twig with jquery and jsroutingbundle. how could reload that part of twig?

Comment: You can't, twig is rendered on the server, while js is rendered on the client. You can maybe if you use twig.js

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="divId"> 
    {{Render (controller ('BlogBundle: Post: list', {'limit': 2})}} 
</div>

<button onClick="refreshFunctionName()"> Button Refresh Text </div>

<script>

    function refreshFunctionName()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{{ path('theRoutingToBlogBundlePostListAction') }}",
            data: '',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $('#divId').html(data);
            },
            error: function(){},
            complete: function(){}
        });
    }

</script>
```